# Linker error: unresolved symbol, when library formally included

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, symbols

Linker gives me a fatal error in Inject_mod.obj file calling:

`NtQuerySystemInformation@16`
and
`RtlAdjustPrivilege@16`

which were defined in my ntdll.h I added externally to my project. But it seems like compiler/linker somehow doesn't see it, etc.

Using: VC 2013 on Win8.1, project initially created on Win7

[image: Here's linker error and function definition in header]

UPD: Project Explorer tree: http://floomby.ru/s2/setKB5. Some words've been blured in case of confidence. Additional Dependencies contain my external ntdll.h leading to ntdll.lib

Comment: Could you please extend to full english sentences.

Comment: I'm not sure just adding the *.lib to the project is what you should do. You should probably add it to the linker dependencies in the project settings instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: They are internal Windows implementation functions that were not meant to be used by applications and are subject to change in  Windows revisions.  There is no import library available in the Windows SDK that declares them, you don't have ntdll.lib, so the linker is always going to complain about them.  Only way you can hack it is by using GetProcAddress() to find the exported function in ntdll.dll

Comment: I have my own ntdll.lib used im project, and ive added it to dependencies and the project 'includes'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a lib file by just copying it in the solution view in Visual Studio.

You need to add `ntdll.lib` or any static-library dependency in the linker `Input->Additional Dependencies` pane.

Since you're trying to use `NtQuerySystemInformation` [be aware that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509(v=vs.85).aspx)

> [NtQuerySystemInformation may be altered or unavailable in future versions of Windows. Applications should use the alternate functions listed in this topic.]

Comment: I've added it to linker, of course. Thanks for the link by the way. But i have my own ntdll.lib where NtQuerySystemInformation is defined extensively. It should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: Check for the signature you're using and make sure they match